# Facing OCR multilanguage problem, how to ignore other langs from extracting

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am tryin to OCR an image which contains multiple language(English & Hindi) when I OCR it with py-tesseract the Hindi language words are translated into English words resulting in meaningless strings, so is there anyway to detect only English letters from an image and ignore other languages?

I tried langdetect libraries, re etc.. nothing helped

Here is the program

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
[enter image description here][1]
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Open the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray_image = image.convert("L")
    
    # Apply any additional preprocessing steps if needed (e.g., thresholding)
    
    return gray_image

def ocr_with_whitelist(image_path, whitelist):
    # Specify the list of languages to use for OCR
    languages = 'eng'  # English
    
    # Preprocess the image
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

    # Perform OCR with specified languages
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_image, lang=languages)
    
    # Filter out characters not in the whitelist
    filtered_text = ''.join(char for char in extracted_text if char in whitelist)

    return filtered_text

image_path = 'aadhaar_front.png'
whitelist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/:=, \n'

extracted_text = ocr_with_whitelist(image_path, whitelist)
print(extracted_text)
```

[Output of  extracted texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3HD5.png)